# Outputting .Css file asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, sass, streamwriter, writefile

I am working on a asp.net webforms project. I wanted to know if it is possible to output a minified CSS file to my specific .aspx page. is it possible to do it with a stream writer class? Apologies if the question is not the clearest I have experience with mvc .net core, asp web forms not so much.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Now what's your question?

Comment: Well i suppose my question is how would i got about doing it ? I cant seem to fine any good  documentation online. apologies if my questions are not well explained , im somewhat of a newbie.

Comment: Well that's a broad question. Depends on how you want to go about implementing it.

Comment: I need to output the css file as an input style so like <style><% WriteFile("/content/project/css/foo-foo-min.css") %></style>

Comment: I dont now actually how to write that css file inline like that

Comment: Why do you want to inline it? Why not use a `<link>` element to point to a URL, and then serve the file at that URL?

Comment: @mason has the point, you might found yourself stuck with a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)